# Use Updated API data(From UseEffect) to Update Another State Value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, use-effect

I have an application that gets movie information from an API as an array using the UseEffect hook and stores the response in state (**movies**), I also have a function (**getIndexMovie**) that gets a random movie object from the stored array of movies and stores the returned object in another state (**selectedMovie**). I would like to display a random movie information whenever the page loads, how can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState<TrendingMovieResultModel[]>([]);
const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState<SelectedMovieModel>({
    "backdrop_path": "",
    "title": "",
    "original_language": "",
    "original_title": "",
    "poster_path": "",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 0,
    "vote_count": 0,
    "overview": "",
    "release_date": "",
    "id": 0
  });

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}trending/all/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setMovies(data.results);        
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  }, []);  

  const getRand = (max: number) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

//where can i call this function ?
  const getIndexMovie = () => {
    const randomIndex = getRand(movies.length);
    const { 
            title, backdrop_path, original_language,  original_title, poster_path, 
            video, vote_average, vote_count, overview, release_date,
            id 
          } = movies[randomIndex];

    setSelectedMovie({ backdrop_path, title, original_language, original_title,
      poster_path, video, vote_average, vote_count, overview, release_date, id
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by adding it to your `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${baseUrl}trending/all/day?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setMovies(data.results);
      const randIndex = getRand(data.results.length);
      setSelectedMovie(data.results[randIndex]);       
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  }, []);
```